# Prove or disprove the average sum of two odd integers is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Prove or disprove: The average of any two odd integers is even.

How do I start this?

I tried this one: The average of  1 and 3 is 2 which is even. so it's true.

is this the right way to prove the statement?

Comment: What does the "typical" odd integer look like? No wait, first: what does the typical even integer look like?

Comment: 2,4,6,8,...etc  ;

Comment: Good, almost there -- you missed one: 0 is even. But anyway, either you can prove the statement outright, OR you can find a counterexample. Two consecutive odd numbers (3 and 5, 11 and 13) will never do because their average is the even number between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to prove a conjecture in mathematics is as follows:

- To prove the statement holds you have to show that it is true for *all* odd integers.
- To disprove the statement you only have to find **one** counter-example where the statement does not hold: $\cfrac{5+13}{2}=9\ne$ even integer.

Hence, you now conclude that you have disproved the statement.

QED.

(This is an abbreviation for the Latin phrase "quod erat demonstrandum" ("that which was to be demonstrated"), a notation which is often placed at the end of a mathematical proof to indicate its completion.) or you can use $\fbox{}$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

$3+7\over2$$=5$. You should try some more examples.

Comment: The answer isnt defined for this question as it can be proved or disproved . It depends on the values you take for odd numbers.